# Notation: what is He(A) and Sh(A)?

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory

In the book "Nonlinear Dynamical Systems and Control: A Lyapunov-Based Approach" in "Conventions and Notation" section there are two expressions with "fairly standard notation":
$$\text{He} A = \frac{A + A^{*}}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad \text{Sh} A = \frac{A - A^{*}}{2},$$
where $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix.
Why $\text{He}$ and $\text{Sh}$? Do they have some special names and properties?
$\text{Sh}A$ looks like hyperbolic sine in exponential form, but I can't see the connection between these two...

Comment: The matrix $A$ must be square ($m=n$) for $A \pm A^*$ to be defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It stands for the **Hermitian part** and the **skew-Hermitian** part of the matrix $A$.

See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitianPart.html, for example.

Comment: Thanks! To which branch of mathematics are these things related? Indeed, there are notions of Hermitian and skew-Hermitian matrices in linear algebra and, but I've never met the partition of Hermitian matrices before.

Comment: Yes, this is just linear algebra. But it's a special case of something more general: in any abelian group $G$, if you have an *involution* $\sigma\colon G \to G$ (a group homomorphism such that $\sigma(\sigma(x))=x$ for all $x \in G$), then any $x$ can be uniquely written as $x=x_s+x_a$ where $x_s$ is symmetric with respect to $\sigma$ and $x_a$ is antisymmetric with respect to $\sigma$, meaning that $\sigma(x_s)=x_s$ and $\sigma(x_a)=-x_a$. Indeed, $x_s=\frac12(x+\sigma(x))$ and $x_a=\frac12(x-\sigma(x))$ do the trick.

Comment: In this case, the involution is Hermitian transpose: $\sigma(A)=A^*$. Another instance is the splitting of a function $f \colon \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ into an even and an odd part, which is induced by the involution $\sigma$ that maps the function $f(x)$ to the function $f(-x)$.